# For what function does the homogeneity of lower Lebesgue integral fail?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples

Recall the definition of the lower Lebesgue integral: suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^{d}\to [0,+\infty]$ and are not necessarily measurable. Then $$\underline{\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}}f(x)\mathrm{d} x=\sup\limits_{0\leq h\leq f,\;h\text{ simple}}\mathrm{simple}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}h(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

It is obvious that if $c\in[0,+\infty)$ then we have $$\underline{\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}}cf(x)\mathrm{d}x = c\cdot \underline{\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}}f(x)\mathrm{d}x$$ If $f$ is measurable the equality holds if $c=+\infty$. However, I would like to have an example, when this is not true for $c=+\infty$ (of course, then $f$ must be non measurable).

The first idea that I had was to construct a function that is strictly positive everywhere (so that $+\infty\cdot f$ is equal to infinity at some set of positive measure), but at any set of positive measure it has a sequence of arbitrarily small values. So I took $q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap [-1,1]$ and for every $q$ considered shifts of Vitali set. Note that any measurable subset of Vitali set is a null set, but that does not help much, since any measurable $E_{i}$, on which simple function does not change its value, can contain some shift of Vitali set and some subset of other shift. Thus, one can't assign only one value to these shifts; In some sense, the desired function should change faster. I then thought of additive function, that is not continuous (and then its graph is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$), but I suppose it does not work either.

I would not like to get the answer right away, but any hints are welcome

Comment: Suppose that $E_{i}$ (measurable set, on which simple funtion $h$ does not change its value) is contained in a union of some shifts: $(V+p)\cup(V+q)$. Can one deduce that both $(V+p)\cap E$ and $(V+q)\cap E$ should be measurable? If so, $E_{i}$ must either be a null set or contain some shift, so we are left to ensure that $f$ takes arbitrarily small values on each shift

Comment: Take a family of sequences $\{x_{i}^{(n)}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ such that for any $n$ we have $\lim\limits_{i\to\infty} x_{i} = 0$ (but for any $i$ $x_{i}\neq 0$) and $y_{n} = \sup\limits_{i\in\mathbb{N}}x^{(n)}_{i}$ is a decreasing sequence tending to $0$. To some points of $V+q_{n}$ (suppose that we enumerated all rationals in $[-1,1]$) we assign sequence $\{x_{i}^{(n)}\}$. Values at other points choose arbitrarily (but not $0$), so that they are less than $y_{n}$.

Comment: It follows that if $E_{i}$ contains countably many shifts, then it contains some subsequence of $y_{n}$, so any simple function must be identically $0$ on this set $E_{i}$. Suppose that $E_{i}$ contains only finitely many pieces of shifts, say $V+q_{1},\ldots,V+q_{n}$. But then take $$A = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n}(V+q_{i})$$ and consider shifts from the set $\mathbb{Q}\cap [-1,1]\backslash \{q_{1},\ldots,q_{n}\}$. It follows that $E_{i}$ must be a null set? Either way, simple integral of $h$ is equal to zero, and so does lower Lebesgue integral of $f$